# Tool for only combining JavaScript files, without compressing or uglyfying?

Tags: javascript

I have a backbone app with over 50 small JavaScript files. Now I want to put all those in one single file, but it should still be readable, so:

**Is there a tool for combining JavaScript files without minifying or uglyfying them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` (standard on UNIX-like systems).

```
cat foo.js bar.js > combined.js
```

You may run into problems if you have any scripts that do not end with a new line while depending on semi-colon insertion for that line.

Comment: For this you have to type name of all files? Or can I define a list of all files to be combined and read that from a text file?

Comment: It's a program that takes a list of arguments. Standard shell expansion rules apply. `cat *.js` or `find . -name '*.js' | xargs cat` or `xargs cat < list_of_files.txt`